Pyserial to HC-06 Problem (Does not affect all computers)
I have a simple python gui script utilizing pyserial to connect to an HC-06 device. Below is the standard pyserial open process I am using:
com_port = bt_spp.get_spp_com_port(PortAddresses[index]) #Note
print("Connecting to: " + com_port)
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = com_port
ser.timeout = 10
time.sleep(1)
ser.open()
serialConnectSuccess = True
time.sleep(1)

Note: This line just returns the COM port (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53440328/24647047) which I've confirmed to match the Windows configured COM port.
On one customer Windows 11 device I am having an error raised as part of the ser.open():
could not open port 'COM4': OSError(22, 'Element not found.', None, 1168)
I have run this program on around 10-15 other devices running a variety of Windows 10 and 11 computers (with different Bluetooth adapters and driver versions) and have not been able to duplicate. On this device I have confirmed that the COM port exists in the Bluetooth (The names have been whited out but are correct) when going to run the application:
Bluetooth COM Ports
I have also tried all combinations of resetting devices, unpairing and re-pairing, driver updates, and COM port reassignment.
The error is raised from the serialwin32.py open which utilizes win32.CreateFile :
self._port_handle = win32.CreateFile(
    port,
    win32.GENERIC_READ | win32.GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,  # exclusive access
    None,  # no security
    win32.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | win32.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    0)
if self._port_handle == win32.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
    self._port_handle = None    # 'cause __del__ is called anyway
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))

The main concern is that this is a problem on future PCs even if rare, to give a work around/troubleshooting steps. Any help is greatly appreciated!
